# pausing and resuming a setTimeout program

Tags: javascript, button, settimeout, resume, pause

Before yesterday I literally have never written anything with Javascript.  I am brand new at this.  I have written macros in excel but I am very familiar with computers.  I am trying to write a program so I can have an HTML file open in my browser that will have a button.  When I press the button I want it to count down from a random number, and then when the count down is over it will play a beep and randomly pick a text from a list of items.

I have most of this down and working (remember this is my first ever program) but I want to incorporate a feature that allows me to pause the timer so I can resume it later.  I have included some numbers here that work but this is just testing.

I have been looking online at other "pause and resume" style questions but I'm a little confused.  This is super new to me.

Here is my program so far....

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Javascript CART breakdown calculator</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="breakdown_item"></p>

<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, my_random_number*1000);">start timer</button>

<script>
var my_random_number, low, high;
low = 1;
high = 5;
my_random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * high) + low;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = my_random_number;

var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext ||  window.webkitAudioContext)();

function myFunction(frequency, duration, callback) {
    duration = 10000 / 1000;     // the 10000 used to be 'duration' 

    // create Oscillator node
    var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

    oscillator.type = 'square';
    oscillator.frequency.value = 500; // value in hertz
    oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);

    oscillator.onended = callback;
    oscillator.start(0);
    oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + duration);

    var random_breakdown_event, low_event, high_event;
    low_event = 1
    high_event = 9
    random_breakdown_event = Math.floor(Math.random() * high_event) + low_event;

    var text
    if (random_breakdown_event == 1) text = "blown engine";
    if (random_breakdown_event == 2) text = "broken transmission";
    if (random_breakdown_event == 3) text = "broken suspension";
    if (random_breakdown_event == 4) text = "broken halfshaft";
    if (random_breakdown_event == 5) text = "broken cv joint";
    if (random_breakdown_event == 6) text = "broken wings";
    if (random_breakdown_event == 7) text = "electrical misfire";
    if (random_breakdown_event == 8) text = "broken fuel pump";
    if (random_breakdown_event == 9) text = "change battery";

    document.getElementById("breakdown_item").innerHTML = text

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to incorporate a way to make this timer pause and resume.

Comment: I am going to try something else with this, but I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments in regards your code.

1) Button event management (valid for all event management)

Try to manage your events unobstrusively (although there's a new tendency to do it inline, for instance with React Components). What unobstrusively means? It means you define your code events outside of the HTML, within the javascript  block.

For instance, if you assign the id="button-timer" to your button you can do something like this:

```
<script>
     var button = document.getElementById('button-timer');
     button.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
</script>
```

Then inside your `myFunction` you can specify the setTimeout. The setTimeout function returns a value you can later use to pause/remove the timeout with a function named `clearTimeout(<timer-reference>)`. So this gives you a hint on how to pause/control the timeouts.

2) Instead of so many if's() just use a Switch statement.
So you would do something like:

```
switch(random_breakdown_event){
    case 1 : // some code;
        break;
    case 3 : // some code
       break;
    default: // default case action
}
```

So hinting you on how to manage a pause/stop process,

```
<button id="button-timer">Start timer</button>
<script>
     var timer=null;

     function myFunction(){
          // Your function does stuff     
     }
     function buttonEventHandler(){
          timer = setTimeout('myFunction', <some-random-time>);
     }
     function pauseStop(){
         clearInterval(timer);
     }
     var button = document.getElementById('button-timer');
     button.addEventListener('click', buttonEventHandler);
</script>
```

This would be a general schema on how your'd control a timer pause action in js code.

Comment: Actually this isn't for any type of class- it's for a game (actually a really old MS dos game) that I enjoy.  I am learning all of this on my own I only picked javascript because I use dosbox to play this game and sound from a webpage will play over the sound of the game when dosbox is open.  I figured I could run this in the background by leaving the html file open in a seperate window with dosbox maximized in front of it.  This is a racing game, but the car never breaks down.  My idea was to have it break down after a random amount of time.  I want to be able to pause it.

Comment: Nah, I mentioned homework generally. Like when someone does something for you so you are released from the thought process.

Comment: Honestly I am totally clueless about what you posted.  This is not my strong point.  I am a hands on person

Comment: I added some code at the end of my answer that gives you a better clue based on actual code.

Comment: There you have even better code at the end, that'd hint you on how to control the timer.

Comment: I spent hours yesterday and 3 today playing with it trying to get it to work.  No luck so far.  Right now I am just using it without pausing.

Comment: can anyone else help?